# how to get dates in reverse order in php?

Tags: php, arrays, date

I build a php page in which i want to get dates in reverse order how i do this?

Here is my code:

```
$dates = array();
$timestamp = time();
for ($i = 0 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) {
   $dates[$i]= date('m-d-Y', $timestamp);
   $timestamp -= 24 * 3600;
}
```

and here is my output

```
 Array ( [0] => 02-01-2014 [1] => 01-31-2014 [2] => 01-30-2014 [3] => 01-29-2014 [4] => 01-28-2014 [5] => 01-27-2014 [6] => 01-26-2014 [7] => 01-25-2014 [8] => 01-24-2014 [9] => 01-23-2014 [10] => 01-22-2014 [11] => 01-21-2014 [12] => 01-20-2014 [13] => 01-19-2014 [14] => 01-18-2014 [15] => 01-17-2014 [16] => 01-16-2014 [17] => 01-15-2014 [18] => 01-14-2014 [19] => 01-13-2014 [20] => 01-12-2014 [21] => 01-11-2014 [22] => 01-10-2014 [23] => 01-09-2014 [24] => 01-08-2014 [25] => 01-07-2014 [26] => 01-06-2014 [27] => 01-05-2014 [28] => 01-04-2014 [29] => 01-03-2014 [30] => 01-02-2014 )
```

How to store dates in reverse order?

Comment: You can reverse the array: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: i want array([0]=>01-02-2014 and so on

Comment: `$dates[$i]= date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);`

Comment: you dont understand my question i want to reverse the array i want array[0]=array[30] from the above array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse you can use strtotime function

```
<?php 

$dates = array();
//get the last day and go from that day
$timestamp = strtotime('-30 days');

for ($i = 0 ; $i <=30 ; $i++) {

   //insert the date
   $dates[$i]= date('m-d-Y', $timestamp);

   //increase the day
    $timestamp += 24 * 3600;
}

//display the output
print_r($dates);


Array
(
    [0] => 01-02-2014
    [1] => 01-03-2014
    [2] => 01-04-2014
    [3] => 01-05-2014
    [4] => 01-06-2014
    [5] => 01-07-2014
    [6] => 01-08-2014
    [7] => 01-09-2014
    [8] => 01-10-2014
    [9] => 01-11-2014
    [10] => 01-12-2014
    [11] => 01-13-2014
    [12] => 01-14-2014
    [13] => 01-15-2014
    [14] => 01-16-2014
    [15] => 01-17-2014
    [16] => 01-18-2014
    [17] => 01-19-2014
    [18] => 01-20-2014
    [19] => 01-21-2014
    [20] => 01-22-2014
    [21] => 01-23-2014
    [22] => 01-24-2014
    [23] => 01-25-2014
    [24] => 01-26-2014
    [25] => 01-27-2014
    [26] => 01-28-2014
    [27] => 01-29-2014
    [28] => 01-30-2014
    [29] => 01-31-2014
    [30] => 02-01-2014
)
```